# What settings are required in centos network files

Tags: php

I want to access centos remotely:
Below are ifcfg-eth0 file:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
HWADDR=00:0C:29:51:DB:6B
IPADDR=192.168.1.254
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.1.0
ONBOOT=yes
GATEWAY=192.168.128.1
TYPE=Ethernet
UID="bc1cf945-065b-472c-9b6e-16b2180c6e87"
```

Please let me know what other settings need to be done to remotely access files placed at /var/www/html/hello.php
It may be a simple question for somebody but I have been browsing the whole day and I'm unable to achieve it.
192.168.1.254/hello.php

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.1.254` is a private non routable IP address.

It is only accessible by other machines on the same network (`192.168.1.0/24`). From another machine on your local network you should be able to access the web server by the following address `http://192.168.1.254/hello.php` depending on your `VirtualHost` host settings.

If you want to make your centos host accessible from other networks you will need to get a public IP address or modify your NAT type and set up [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on your router.

Comment: Hello robbmj if possible can you please guide me how can I do it I don't know linkup of things to set everything as per my requirement. Can you please guide me step by step to accomplish this. I will be very thankful to you

Comment: Hi @Deepak, it would be very difficult for me to help guide you through this step by step. Please have a look through this site: http://portforward.com/ it will get you going in the right direction.